# Right way to initialise SharedPreference in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am very new to Kotlin. Previously, I used to declare a SharedPreference in an activity as such:

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences main;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        main = getSharedPreferences("main", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

This allowed me to use the `main` instance throughout the class. I would like to achieve a similar functionality. I am currently using `lateinit var` as such:

```
class MainActivityKotlin : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var main : SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        main = getSharedPreferences("main", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }
}
```

But I am not sure if this is the right way of doing it.
Also this is a `var`. As far as I understand, a `val` is usually recommended where the instance will not change (like in this case, `main` will not change once initialised). So is this approach correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `lateinit` is perfectly fine. It's there for this purpose, after all.

There is a slightly cleaner solution you could use, though: lazy-init:

```
val main by lazy { getSharedPreferences("main", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) }
```

This only calls `getSharedPreferences()` when `main` is first referenced, and then stores that instance. It's similar to how things are done in Java, but you don't need to split lines.

Comment: Looks perfect. I can also use `val` instead of `var` using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, a `val` is better. You can obtain one with lazy initialisation:

```
class MainActivityKotlin : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val sharedPrefs by lazy { getSharedPreferences("main", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        /* initialisation is removed from here, as it is now lazy */
    }

    fun otherFunction() {
        // the first use of the shared preference will trigger its initialisation
        val prefInt = sharedPrefs.getInt("key", 0)
    }
}
```